# Hibernate config.Run sql script before init

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using H2-in-memory database in my project, and I want to run few sql-scripts before startup.
Here is my config:

> hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
>   hibernate.show_sql=true
>   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
>   hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/db/scripts/schema.sql,/db/scripts/insert-users.sql

But it doesn't work. If I change `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create` or `create-drop` it tries to create tables based on annotated entities. But I want to run my own sql script with creation of tables and insertion of users.
Java config:

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            new String[]{"org.training.ytaranau"});
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}
 Properties hibernateProperties() {
    return new Properties() {
        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers",
                    "true");
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files",
                    env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files"));
        }
    };
}
```

Am I able to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can set below properties for the hibernate, then you can execute some scripts.

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source
javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source

     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/drop-script.sql"/>
     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/create-script.sql"/>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: @VladimirVagaytsev it is for JPA, you can configure it in persitence.xml